# Find inverse of (many) sparse (but block-diagonal) matrices in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-inverse

My problem is this: I have a very large number (millions) of large matrices to invert, and I would like to do it with TensorFlow. In general this could be a rather hard problem, however my matrices are sparse, in particular they have an (irregular) block diagonal structure. So mathematically speaking, one can find the inverse of the full matrix by doing a bunch of inverses of much smaller matrices instead, which is much faster to do.

However, I want to write some general-purpose code to do this inversion, where the structure and size of the block-diagonal matrices will vary between problems. So it would be nice to have an algorithm that can figure out the block diagonal structure itself and make use of it, and which can work with sparse matrices as input and output (since there is never any need to store the zillions of off-block-diagonal elements, and it is more convenient to keep the block-diagonal "package" together, from a user perspective).

I see that TensorFlow has SparseTensor objects, but I can't find too much about algorithms that can use them. Am I lucky and a nice matrix inversion algorithm for block-SparseTensors already exists? I guess it should not be so hard to write one, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Edit: Ahh, I should mention that the block-diagonal structure will be the exact same for all the matrices to be inverted. So the plan was to stack all the matrices in one giant 3D tensor (well as many as can fit in RAM anyway).